# std::forward with templated overloaded function

Tags: templates, c++11, move-semantics

I've got no idea why compiler gives me warnings about template instantiations.

Thats a piece of code which runs just fine and outputs lvalue/rvalue properly:

```
//template<typename T>
void overloaded(const /*T*/std::string& in)
{
    std::cout << "lvalue" << std::endl;
}

//template<typename T>
void overloaded(/*T*/std::string&& in)
{
    std::cout << "rvalue" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void pass(T&& in)
{
    overloaded(std::forward<T>(in));
}

int main()
{
    std::string a;
    pass(a);
    pass(std::move(a));
    getchar();
}
```

But i need to use it with templated type. So modifying the "overloaded" functions to

```
template<typename T>
void overloaded(const T& in)
{
    std::cout << "lvalue" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void overloaded(T&& in)
{
    std::cout << "rvalue" << std::endl;
}
```

Gives template instantiations warnings, (when to me its clear T should be std::string), and console outputs rvalue 2 times instead of lvalue first.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc00c140c9a8e208

Comment: `T&&` is a forwarding reference, i.e., if `T` is a type template parameter, it is no longer a regular rvalue reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates such as `T&&` are special.  They are called "forwarding references".  They have special deduction rules for functions like:

```
template<typename T>
void overloaded(T&& in)
```

Assume for a moment that `overloaded` is not overloaded.  If you pass an lvalue expression of type `std::string` to `overloaded`, `T` will deduce as `std::string&`.  If you pass an rvalue expression of type `std::string` to `overloaded`, `T` will deduce to `std::string`.  You can use this knowledge to do this:

```
template<typename T>
void overloaded(T&& in)
{
    if (std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value)
        std::cout << "lvalue" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "rvalue" << std::endl;
}
```

In general, it is an anti-pattern to overload `T&&` templates with anything else.  These special templates come in handy when you want to catch everything.

Comment: Wow i was completly unaware of that! Thanks!